Непонятные лаги видео в видео плеере в unity 2D
Я сделал видео плеер на сцене. Видео плеер состоит из raw image с render mode = Render Texture, текстура для рендера задана. Видео плеер вроде бы хорошо работает(в редакторе unity просто отлично), но при компиляции в android и последующем запуске игры видео то сильно заикаются, то лагают. Это при том что все видео я сжал(размер от 100 kb до 1,5 mb), формат mp4, кодек H.264. Эта проблема появилась не сразу, а на втором запуске игры на android телефоне, на первом запуске было всё относительно нормально. Как это исправить?
